# how to subgraph an igraph object (graph) using vertices attribute that has NA values - R

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, subgraph

I'm trying to subgraph a graph using igraph in by filtering vertices based on the value of an attribute of the vertices. the attribute values can be NA and I want those with NA values to be excluded.

here is my graph

```
> require(igraph)
> graph <- make_ring(7)
> V(graph)$name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
> V(graph)$att1 <- c(1,2,NA,1,2,3,NA)
> subgraph <- make_ego_graph(graph, order=1, c("A", "D", "F"))  # this works because i'm using the names of vertices but it's not what I want
```

all i'm trying to do here is to get the names of the vertices that have att1==1, and use that instead of to subgraph. But this doesn't work and gives me the following error

```
 > V(graph)[att1 == 1, na_ok = TRUE]$name  

    Error in if (is.numeric(v) && any(v < 0)) { :    missing value where
        TRUE/FALSE needed
```

how do I get the vector of the names for vertices that have att1 == 1 to pass it to the subgraph function?
or is there another way to subgraph using an attribute value?
I want the subgraph to include all the vertices selected (att1 == 1) AND the vertices that connect to those vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
require(igraph)
graph <- make_ring(7)
V(graph)$name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
V(graph)$att1 <- c(1,2,NA,1,2,3,NA)

V(graph)$name[which(V(graph)$att1 == 1)] 
#> [1] "A" "D"
```

Lately I became a fan of the `tidygraph` package which is a wrapper around `igraph`, so graphs can be manipulated using `dplyr` and other `tidyverse` packages. In this case:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(dplyr)

as_tbl_graph(graph) %>% 
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  filter(att1 == 1) %>% 
  pull(name)
#> [1] "A" "D"
```

Or directly subset the graph (afaik)

```
graph_tidy <- as_tbl_graph(graph) %>% 
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  filter(att1 == 1)

graph_tidy
#> # A tbl_graph: 2 nodes and 0 edges
#> #
#> # An undirected simple graph with 2 components
#> #
#> # Node Data: 2 x 2 (active)
#>   name   att1
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A         1
#> 2 D         1
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 0 x 2
#> # ... with 2 variables: from <int>, to <int>
```

Comment: tidygraph seems very useful. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @JBGruber, is `graph_tidy` can be plotted using `plot()`  function of `igrapgh` package? or it needs to be converted to an `igrapgh object`?

Comment: The `igraph` class is preserved as a fallback. So yes, you can simply use `plot()`. I would recommend to look into the companion package from the same author for plotting though: `ggraph`

Comment: @JBGruber, thanks. can I add other characteristics such as `order=2` of nodes, or `degree>0` following the methodology of your code?

Comment: You can use all `dplyr` verbs to manipulate the nodes or edges `data.frame`s.

Comment: @JBGruber, thanks, I need to find immediate neighbours `(order=1) `of some nodes. And `(order=1)` is not in nodes or edges data frames. Is there any way I can use `dplyr` and  `tidygrapgh` to grapgh immediate neighbours of specific nodes?